# Regular Expression to match open and closed html tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to come up with Regular Expression to return true if the a closed html tag is matched with an open one in specific text that gets passed in JavaScript. If there is an unmatched tag, it should return false;

For example, if the following text is passed `"<div>Test</div>"` it should return true 
but if the following text gets passed `"<div>Test</div><div>Boom"` it should return false

I can only get it to match the first div tags to return true with the following expression

```
    var text = "<div>Test</div>; 
    var text2 = "<div>Test</div><div>; 
    var regex = /[^<>]*<(\w+)(?:(?:\s+\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)>[^<>]*<\/\1+\s*>[^<>]*|[^<>]*<\w+(?:(?:\s+\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)\/>[^<>]*|<!--.*?-->|^[^<>]+$/;
    var match = regex.test(text);
    console.log(match); // true
    var match = regex.test(text2);
    console.log(match2); // still true should be false
```

How can I fix it so it functions the way I want it to.

Comment: I would not suggest using a regex for this... even if possible I doubt it would be understandable.. does it have to be a regex?

Comment: This can be ... problematic.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: [Obligatory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1223693) ;) Use a proper HTML parser.

Comment: As the bowl of petunias thought..."Oh no, not again!"

Comment: What, are there at least 10 of these questions per day you think?

Comment: I don't need it to parse all html tags.. I just want a reg ex to be able to detect if a tag has a closing one in Javascript. I am open to other suggestions besides html validator services. Is there some query library that can do this?

Comment: @CodeCrack, it's known (from formal languages theory) that regexes can't validate parenthesis sequence. So it can't validate HTML neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `test` method returns true for `match2` because **it has found a match**.

In order to fix it, change your regex this way:

```
^(?:<(\w+)(?:(?:\s+\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)>[^<>]*<\/\1+\s*>|<\w+(?:(?:\s+\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)\/>|<!--.*?-->|[^<>]+)*$
```

#### Description (click to enlarge)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/r2LsN/

#### Discussion

The regex defines all the allowed patterns firstly:

1. Tags with body:  `<tag>...</tag>`
2. Tags without body: `<tag/>` (here we can find zero or more spaced before `/`)
3. Comments `<!-- ... -->`
4. Any text that is not `<` or `>`.

then these patterns can appear zero or more times between the beginning and the end of the tested string: `^(?:pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|pattern4)*$`.

Comment: Doesn't work with nested tags `<a><c>b</c></a>`

Comment: @Barmaley.exe OP has explicitly denied `<` and `>` inside tags (`[^<>]+`).

Comment: yes, but he haven't said that it's desired behaviour.

Comment: @Barmaley.exe OP talks about a *specific text*. What if this specific text doesn't contain tag inside tag? We can't say because we don't fully know OP context.

Comment: does he? I see only `For example`. If you need to know context, there is an "Add comment" button.

Comment: @Barmaley.exe Please, read the second line in the first paragraph from OP's question.